# How do I define multiple sources in the Source of a Treelist field?

Tags: tree-list

I am trying to add multiple root folders to the source field of a treelist template field. For example:

```
Datasource=/sitecore/media library/ | /sitecore/content/
```

I have done this with sitecore query, but treelist does not use sitecore query. This is for Sitecore 7.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will require customization. Luckily for you, Kam has an example available at http://kamsar.net/index.php/2015/05/A-Multiple-Root-Treelist-Field/

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Not to self-promote, but I actually wrote a [blog post](http://zacharykniebel.com/blog/sitecore/2016/june/06/creating-a-multi-root-treelist-field-in-sitecore) on how to create a Multi-Root Treelist a little while back, based on Kam's post on multi-root Treelists, enhanced with support for using data source parameters with Sitecore Query and also displaying full item paths next to the item names in the tree.

**Implementation:**

In addition to the code, don't forget that you will need to add a new item for the field type under */sitecore/system/Field types/List Types* in the core database.

Below are all the classes and config files that you will need (assuming that you are using Solr; otherwise you may need to update the Custom.FieldTypes.Solr.config to be Lucene-friendly):

*MultiRootTreeList.cs:*

```cs
/// <summary>
/// This field type is like a tree list, but you can specify more than one root item to select from
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Credit to Kam Figy for providing the foundation for this solution: http://kamsar.net/index.php/2015/05/A-Multiple-Root-Treelist-Field/
/// 
/// The data source roots are specified using pipe delimiting just like regular Sitecore Query language. This is great when a field needs to allow, for example,
/// the selection of both videos and photos. 
/// 
/// Note that this solution also requires a config setting to be added for the field type. For example, the following would be added to the the 
/// sitecore/fieldTypes path: 
///
/// <fieldType name="Multi-Root Treelist" type="Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField,Sitecore.Kernel" /> 
///
/// Additionally, the field type should be added to the ContentSearch configuration, if using ContentSearch
/// </remarks>
public class MultiRootTreeList : TreeList
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Prefix that all Sitecore queries should start with
    /// </summary>
    private const string QueryPrefix = "query:";
    /// <summary>
    /// Parameter key for the DataSource parameter of the Source field
    /// </summary>
    private const string DataSourceParameterKey = "datasource";

    private string[] _sources;
    /// <summary>
    /// The split sources within the <seealso cref="TreeList.Source"/> property
    /// </summary>
    public string[] Sources => _sources ?? (_sources = GetSources());

    private string[] _dataSources;
    /// <summary>
    /// The datasources retrieved from the <seealso cref="Sources"/>
    /// </summary>
    public string[] DataSources
    {
        get
        {
            // if we already found the sources, don't do all this cumbersome logic again
            if (_dataSources != null)
            {
                return _dataSources;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Source) || global::Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase == null || ItemID == null)
            {
                return (_dataSources = new string[] { });
            }

            var contextDb = global::Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase;

            // the current item, from which relatative queries are executed
            var currentItem = contextDb.GetItem(ItemID);

            return (_dataSources = Sources
                .Select(source => GetDatasource(source, currentItem))
                // decided not to fall back here; if the datasource wasn't found then remove it, rather than show a default node
                .Where(datasource => datasource != null)
                .ToArray());
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");

        // if this is an event, just run the base logic and return
        if (global::Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.IsEvent)
        {
            return;
        }

        base.OnLoad(args);

        // find the existing TreeviewEx that the base OnLoad added, get a ref to its parent, and remove it from controls
        var existingTreeView = (TreeviewEx)WebUtil.FindControlOfType(this, typeof(TreeviewEx));
        var treeviewParent = existingTreeView.Parent;

        existingTreeView.Parent.Controls.Clear(); // remove stock treeviewex, we replace with multiroot

        // find the existing DataContext that the base OnLoad added, get a ref to its parent, and remove it from controls
        var dataContext = (DataContext)WebUtil.FindControlOfType(this, typeof(DataContext));
        var dataContextParent = dataContext.Parent;

        dataContextParent.Controls.Remove(dataContext); // remove stock datacontext, we parse our own

        // create our MultiRootTreeview to replace the TreeviewEx
        var impostor = new EnhancedMultiRootTreeview
        {
            ID = existingTreeView.ID,
            DblClick = existingTreeView.DblClick,
            Enabled = existingTreeView.Enabled,
            DisplayFieldName = existingTreeView.DisplayFieldName
        };

        // parse the data source and create appropriate data contexts out of it
        var dataContexts = ParseDataContexts(dataContext);

        // join the IDs of all of the DataContext objects together, to be added as controls
        impostor.DataContext = 
            string.Join(
                "|", 
                dataContexts
                    .Select(dc => dc.ID));

        // add the new DataContext controls into the selection pane
        foreach (var context in dataContexts)
        {
            dataContextParent.Controls.Add(context);
        }

        // inject our replaced control where the TreeviewEx originally was
        treeviewParent.Controls.Add(impostor);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all of the datasources from the Source field
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual string[] GetSources()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Source))
        {
            return new string[] {};
        }

        var datasource = global::Sitecore.StringUtil.ExtractParameter(DataSourceParameterKey, Source).Trim();
        datasource = string.IsNullOrEmpty(datasource)
            ? Source
            : datasource;

        return datasource.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the item path to the datasource item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">The source used to find the datasource item</param>
    /// <param name="currentItem">The current item</param>
    protected virtual string GetDatasource(string source, Item currentItem)
    {
        Item datasourceItem = null;

        // if the source is a query then run the query from the current item
        if (source.StartsWith(QueryPrefix))
        {
            try
            {
                var results = LookupSources.GetItems(currentItem, source);
                datasourceItem = results
                    .FirstOrDefault(item => item != null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error($"Treelist field failed to execute query: '{source}'", ex, this);
            }
        }
        // otherwise just get the item specified
        else
        {
            datasourceItem = currentItem.Database.GetItem(source);
        }

        return datasourceItem?.Paths.FullPath;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parses multiple source roots into discrete data context controls (e.g. 'dataSource=/sitecore/content|/sitecore/media library')
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="originalDataContext">The original data context the base control generated. We reuse some of its property values.</param>
    protected virtual DataContext[] ParseDataContexts(DataContext originalDataContext)
    {
        // if there are multiple roots; otherwise, just use the original datasource (shouldn't happen, but just in case...)
        return (DataSources.Any() ? DataSources : new ListString(DataSource).AsEnumerable())
            .Select(datasource => CreateDataContext(originalDataContext, datasource))
            .ToArray();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a DataContext control for a given Sitecore path data source
    /// </summary>
    protected virtual DataContext CreateDataContext(DataContext baseDataContext, string dataSource)
    {
        var dataContext = new DataContext
        {
            ID = GetUniqueID("D"),
            Filter = baseDataContext.Filter,
            DataViewName = "Master"
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DatabaseName))
        {
            dataContext.Parameters = "databasename=" + DatabaseName;
        }

        dataContext.Root = dataSource;
        dataContext.Language = Language.Parse(ItemLanguage);

        return dataContext;
    }
}
```

*EnhancedMultiRootTreeView.cs:*

```cs
public class EnhancedMultiRootTreeview : MultiRootTreeview
{
    protected override string GetHeaderValue(Item item)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(item, "item");

        var nodeTitle = string.IsNullOrEmpty(DisplayFieldName) ? item.DisplayName : item[DisplayFieldName];
        nodeTitle = string.IsNullOrEmpty(nodeTitle) ? item.DisplayName : nodeTitle;
        // you can get fancy here and make the format of the nodeTitle manageable in config
        nodeTitle = $"{nodeTitle}  -  <span>({item.Paths.FullPath})</span>";

        return nodeTitle;
    }
}
```

*Custom.FieldTypes.config:*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <fieldTypes>
      <fieldType name="Multi-Root Treelist" type="Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField,Sitecore.Kernel" patch:after="fieldType[@name='Treelist']" />
    </fieldTypes>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

*Custom.FieldTypes.Solr.config:*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
          <fieldMap type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrFieldMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldTypeName">
              <fieldType fieldTypeName="multi-root treelist"   returnType="stringCollection" />
            </fieldTypes>
          </fieldMap>
          <fieldReaders type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.FieldReaderMap, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <mapFieldByTypeName hint="raw:AddFieldReaderByFieldTypeName">
              <fieldReader fieldTypeName="multi-root treelist"    fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.MultiListFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
            </mapFieldByTypeName>
          </fieldReaders>
        </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: A problem I noticed with this is that the `base.OnLoad()` call will throw an exception when multiple datasources are present. Is there a known fix for this?